# Where is the license information for an Android app displayed?

Tags: google-play-store

I assume that all Android apps are licensed. However I can not find the  license information anywhere. I thought it would be available when the app is viewed using Google Play Store so you could decide whether or not you were happy with the license before downloading the app. I can not find it on the Play Store or anywhere else. Where is it please?

Comment: Whilst I'm inclined to agree this is off-topic, Google's view seems to be that licensing is not a *salient* for Play Store users, who primarily care about the *cost* of an app.  If licensing is important to you (good for you!), consider using the [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/) repository and associated tool, where licensing is a salient, and the information is displayed alongside every listed app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get license information from Apache.

These websites contain open-source code. For example:
https://android.googlesource.com